# Getting Process Desktop

Tags: windows, winapi, process, desktop

As part of a project I'm making I create and use a new desktop by using [`CreateDesktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124.aspx), `SwitchDesktop`, `SetThreadDesktop`... et al.

Once a new desktop is created and switched to a process is created via [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) and the handle is stored so that when the desktop is closed I may terminate the process using `TerminateProcess` so that Windows can delete/close the desktop as all processes in a desktop must be terminated before the desktop can be closed.

However programs that use a file dialog open the user to executing arbitrary processes in the desktop, for example if I were to create a notepad.exe process for this desktop a user could click on `File > Open` navigate to `%windir%` and then execute `explorer.exe` which would actually open in the desktop giving it a taskbar, start button, and of course the ability to do anything they want.

The problem is that when something like this happens and the desktop is switched back to the main desktop my program only knows of and can terminate the processes it has started, leaving `explorer.exe` and any other processes left in the desktop to be in process limbo, preventing the desktop from being closed.

I was thinking about using [`EnumProcesses`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629.aspx), then get a handle for each and hopefully finding a way to retrieve its desktop name so that I can compare it to mine and terminate the process.

Would this be the correct approach to this problem? If so what WinAPI function could I use to retrieve a process' desktop name? However if it is *not* the correct approach what can I do to fix, prevent, or mitigate this?

Comment: There's [`EnumDesktopWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682615), but just getting processes with top-level windows might not be sufficient. You probably need to kill all processes on the desktop.

Comment: [`GetThreadDesktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683232) should succeed if the thread is running on a desktop that's open in the current process, and should return the existing desktop handle from the process handle table (which is why "[y]ou do not need to call the `CloseDesktop` function to close the returned handle"). You can walk the threads on the system using the [Tool Help library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681926) and create a list of process handles to terminate.

Comment: @eryksun Worked perfectly, walked the threads and processes in the new desktop to get the processes in that desktop. Would you mind posting that as an answer so that I may upvote and accept it?

Comment: I'd also try to gracefully exit as many processes as possible via `EnumDesktopWindows` and `SendMessageTimeout` to send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the top-level windows. The timeout should give the user a reasonable amount of time to confirm dialogs. Then I'd terminate whichever processes remain.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to solve your problem.

1. Like @eryksun said u can use `EnumDesktopWindows` to get all Top-Level windows and send them as `WM_CLOSE` Message. After that, you can use `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` with a timeout, so you can terminate them after the timeout. You can check the timeout with `WAIT_TIMEOUT`. Here is an example in python:

```py
    import win32api
    import win32con
    import win32event
    import win32gui
    import win32process
    import win32service


    def closeProcessesOnDesk(deskName,timeout):
        print("try to close Processes on given Desktop")
        hwndlist=[]
        try:
            hdesk = win32service.OpenDesktop(deskName,0,False,0)
            hwndlist = hdesk.EnumDesktopWindows()
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Desktop wasn't found. {}".format(ex))
        processlist =[]
        #try to close nicely processes"
        for hwnd in hwndlist:
            # Get the window's process id's
            if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd):
                tid, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
                handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid)
                processlist.append(handle)
            # Ask window nicely to close
                try:
                    win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
                except:
                    pass
            # Allow some time for app to close
        print("Start waiting for processes to close")
        try:
            state = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects(processlist, True, timeout)

            if state == win32con.WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                print("processes didn't close nicely, terminate them")
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error on closing Process. {}".format(ex))
        finally:
            for hproc in processlist:
                if hproc:
                    win32api.TerminateProcess(hproc,0)
                    win32api.CloseHandle(hproc)  

    closeProcessesOnDesk('test',2000)
```

2. Since you have handle of your created Process, you can use it to terminate the whole processtree of this process. In your case every process which will be started with `File > Open` in `notepad.exe` will also be terminated. In python:

```py
import subprocess


def killProcessTree(parent_pid):
    try:
        subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/T', '/PID', str(parent_pid)])
        print("Process killed: %s " % str(parent_pid))
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Process was not killed %s" % ex
```

3. You can also create a new User with restricted rights so he is not even able to start another process. Use `CreateProcessWithLogonW` or `CreateProcessAsUser` to start the process as a "restricted User". But be careful, since winstations and Desktops are security objects you have to add the Users `sid` to the `DACL` of the desktop and winstation.